# Determine if code is being run within a certain block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

Is it possible to determine if code is being run within a certain block? My use case is described below with some pseudo-code mixed in, which demonstrates my idea. Any suggestions are welcome! I want a block on the model to not run when any action on the model is called from within `WatchTower.bulk_operation do; end`.

```
# watch_tower.rb

module WatchTower
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def not_safe_for_bulk
      yield if block_given? && # not called from within bulk_operation block
    end
  end

  def self.bulk_operation
    yield if block_given?
  end
end


# Inside some other file, callbacks on number shouldn't run

WatchTower.bulk_operation do
    5.times { Number.create }
end


# Inside some other file, callbacks on number SHOULD run

Number.create


# number.rb

class Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WatchTower

  not_safe_for_bulk do
    after_commit :something_destructive
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you set Boolean value and set it to true in the block and check the value to see if its set to true that would be your indicator of the block running.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you aren't calling from multiple threads, could something like this work:

```
def self.bulk_operation
  @block_op = true
  yield if block_given?
  @block_op = false
end
```

Then within your method calls, simply check for the `@block_op` flag.

Comment: `bulk_operation` is a module method of `WatchTower`. `Number` will not have access to these instance variables without a very tight binding of `WatchTower.instance_variable_get(:@block_op)` also this alters the return value of `bulk_operation`

Comment: The theory remains the same. I am not writing the code for OP, just displaying a concept.